# Solaris 10 x86 hangs on boot

Tags: solaris, grub, solaris-10

I have an old server running Solaris 10 x86 64 bit. Haven't had issues with it but recently it was powered off without a clean shutdown. That hasn't been an issue in the past with reboots from the power port but this time I'm stuck.

This is what I see when it boots up (part of the left if cut off because of the KVM software)

[image]

It doesn't do anything and doesn't respond to any keyboard commands.

I rebooted into failsafe mode and got an error about a corrupt boot_archive so I had it rebuild it. After that was done tried rebooting and still the same issue.

Rebooted again into failsafe mode and checked the disk for errors (format, analyze, read from [here](http://www.lewiz.org/2007/07/disk-under-solaris.html)) and didn't find any errors, ran fsck on the drive and nothing.

Tried to install grub

```
cd /a/boot/grub
installgrub -fm stage1 stage2 /dev/rdsk/c0d0s0
```

Then rebuilt the boot archive again

```
bootadm update-archive -fv -R /a
```

Output was

```
Forced update of archive requested
Cannot find: /a/etc/cluster/nodeid: No such file or directory
Cannot find: /a/etc/devices/mdi_ib_cache: No such file or directory
Creating ram disk for /a
Updating /a/platform/i86pc/boot/boot_archive...this may take a minute
```

finally unmounted /a and rebooted

```
umount /a
reboot
```

No improvement. Nothing in /a/var/adm/messages since the shutdown. Any other ideas or suggestions on where I can look for next steps?

Set verbose option in grub and see the following before booting stops.

[image]

Comment: Boot in verbose mode.  Select and edit the GRUB line you want to boot.  See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19082-01/819-2379/fwbme/index.html  Add a `-v` to that line, similar to https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E28983/glyas.html (that's for Solaris 11, but the `-v` option is the same)

Comment: Thanks @AndrewHenle at least I'm seeing something now. Not sure what I'm seeing as I've been up all night and haven't worked on this level of this system in a long time. I added a screenshot. Anything jump out at you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the boot archive was indeed corrupted and needed to be rebuilt there was also a different problem. The steps I used to fix the corrupted boot_archive were correct.

Thanks to Andrews comment to my question I was able to turn on verbose output and see where the system was hanging.

From the grub menu I selected the menu item I use to boot normally, hit 'e' to edit and then 'e' again on the kernel line and added -v to the end. Hit enter to save edits and then hit 'b' to boot the edited menu item.

The device that was hanging was pci1458,5004 and after looking through /etc/device_aliases I was able to see that it was the USB controller. After some searching I saw the suggestion to go into the BIOS and disable Legacy USB Support. After doing that the system booted normally. A new device was connected to the server that must have caused the issue.